# Losing data when pass from UIViewController to another class

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin, parameter-passing

I do a simple test app. I pass an int value from UIViewController:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class TestViewController : UIViewController
    {
        Getter gt;
        public TestViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        #region View lifecycle
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            ClickBT.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                gt = new Getter(2);
            };

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
}
```

to another class:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Getter
    {

        public Getter (int x)
        {
            if (x != 0)
                Console.WriteLine ("Value isn't null: ", x);
            else
                Console.WriteLine ("Value is null: ", x);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the button, the result is always:

2015-01-12 09:02:31.063 Teste[5184:107203] Value isn't null:

2015-01-12 09:02:32.453 Teste[5184:107203] Value isn't null:

2015-01-12 09:02:32.630 Teste[5184:107203] Value isn't null:

But I don't have the value. Where should be the value, is blank.

I can't find it on internet...

Comment: You're not using the string formatting overload of Console.WriteLine correctly. Read up on string formatting in C#, it'll help you immensely.

Comment: No, I've tried it. The result is the same.

Comment: I've tried, right now, use the value on a label.
The label shows the value correctly. I think it's a log problem.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The response in the console is correct, but in order to also display the number, you need to change your Console.WriteLine.

***Your example***

```
Console.WriteLine ("Value isn't null: ", x);
```

***What it should be***

```
Console.WriteLine ("Value isn't null: " + x.ToString());
```